# Creating CAT program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extremely new to programming and I am taking classes at the moment. I'm currently using Cygwin to enable UNIX terminal environment to run Python programs. I need to make a similar program with the UNIX utility cat.

What we usually do on the terminal would be: `$cat fileName.txt`

Now what I am trying to achieve is to make a cat program in Python: `$python3 cat.py filename1.txt filename2.txt ...`

I have succeeded to create that, but I am confused as how to implement printing the line number from the external files by implementing `-n`.

How do you run the code `$cat -n filename.txt` as `python3 cat.py -n filename.txt`?

My program looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
numberOfArgs = len(sys.argv)
if numberOfArgs <2:
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: %s inputFile\n' % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

for fileName in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        fh = open(fileName,'r')
    except:
        sys.stderr.write('cannot open input file %s\n' % fileName[1])
        sys.exit(2)
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line, end'')
    fh.close()
```

Comment: Have a look at python [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for it, or the [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/) package.

Answer (score 0):

actually, your code should work as you wish, the only problem I see is in the print line, you have a typo

```
print(line, end='')
```